# How to inspect all elements in android webview

Tags: android, webview, recaptcha, inspect

When i inspect an website with `Chrome` i can to see some `iframe` data like this:
[image]
[Example Chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VxSA.png)

**I did the following solutions :**

- I can inspect **WebView** to get **iFrame** element, but i cant Log these
  content (Like **input** tag, etc...).
- I try to get new recaptcha token from **iframe** link, but received token not valid for its services.
- I tried to get this amount of token using some **JavaScript** code but I always received **null**

it try to get all content by this code:

```
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished: " + url);
            if (url.startsWith(MyApp.LOGIN_URL))
                chkLogin.postDelayed(() -> webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');"),300);

        }
```

But i got this result for iframes:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=-&amp;co=..&amp;hl=en&amp;v=&amp;size=invisible&amp;cb=j2nwbbdqkt4c" width="256" height="60" role="presentation" name="a-axd1alpz93t" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox">(no content in result)</iframe>
```

So, How to get **iFrame** Content in android **WebView**?

Comment: please include content, not pictures of content.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts i do it